# Replacing words

Tags: packages, editors, text

How do I replace a frequent word in my text?
For example, if I want to change all words (transactions) in the reference section to (Tran.) using one command.

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! You can use an editor and change all `(transactions)` to `(Tran.)` ...

Comment: It sounds very much like your question is about how to use an editor to perform a search-and-replace operation, such as replacing all instances of `transactions` with `Tran.`. Such a question is off-topic for this site.